# Compute shared secret for ECDSA<ECP, SHA256> keys with Crypto++

Tags: c++, cryptography, crypto++

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Receive x and y coordinates of a EC public key
2. Generate a random EC public key
3. Compute the shared secret of the two keys

I'm stuck at the last step, from the Documentation is seems like I have to use `ECDH<ECP>::Domain` but nowhere is it explained how to convert the keys into the required `SecByteBlock` objects, how can I do this? Pseudocode follows.

```
std::string x = ...
std::string y = ...

auto make_curve = []{ return ASN1::secp256r1(); };

// Public key
ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::PublicKey g_a;
g_a.Initialize(make_curve(),
               ECP::Point {
                   Integer { x.data() },
                   Integer { y.data() }
               });

// Private key
ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::PrivateKey g_b;
g_b.Initialize(RANDOM_POOL, make_curve());

// Compute shared secret
ECDH<ECP>::Domain agreement { make_curve() };

SecByteBlock shared_secret_buf { agreement.AgreedValueLength() };

agreement.Agree(shared_secret_buf, ???, ???);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Wikipedia page](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Diffie-Hellman#Key_Agreement) shows you show to do this:

So first create a new *key pair* (you never generate just one private key):

```
ECDH < ECP >::Domain dhB( CURVE );
SecByteBlock privB(dhB.PrivateKeyLength()), pubB(dhB.PublicKeyLength());
dhB.GenerateKeyPair(rng, privB, pubB);
```

and then you can perform the key agreement like this:

```
if(!dhB.Agree(shared_secret_buf, privB, pubA))
    throw runtime_error("Failed to reach shared secret (B)");
```

OK, so now you are left with one issue: encoding the public point. Fortunately that has been explained in the Wiki as well, [here](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Diffie-Hellman#Ephemeral_Key_as_.28x.2Cy.29), basically you should just be able to use:

```
void ECP::EncodePoint(BufferedTransformation &bt, const Point &P, bool compressed)
```

Where your `pubA` buffer is put in `&bt` (I hope the input for `&P` is clear, use `false` for compressed).

Basically this returns a byte `04`, then the concatenation of X and Y encoded with the size of the field (big endian).

Note that this just requires an `ECP::Point` and as the key pair generation also doesn't use ECDSA, that part of the code can be stripped out entirely. That's good, because ECDH is a different algorithm and using ECDSA could make the code less portable, e.g. when using the X25519 curve.

Comment: I haven't got a good C++ dev environment setup. This should definitely work, but let me know how you're faring.

Comment: I've added example coded loosely based on your suggestion but unfortunately the agreement step seems to fail.